# How to inject javascript in existing HTML response with node.js and cloudflare workers

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, cloudflare-workers

I have a vanity URL pointing to a GitBook. GitBook doesn't support the insertion of arbitrary javascript snippets. At the moment GitBook has 4 "integrations" only.

I could route through my own VM server to accomplish this, but I have CloudFlare and I want to try out workers. (Javascript running at the CDN edge).

The CloudFlare worker environment makes header injection very easy, but there is no obvious way to do this.

Comment: I'm going to have trouble if the response stream is compressed...

Comment: The SDK includes a TransformStream for modifying the body

Comment: The bytes in Response.body are not compressed (even though the header might say the response itself it gzip compressed)

Comment: Better still, if CloudFlare can add a "beforeHeadClose" string injector. CloudFlare already have the capability for their own scripts (there's one for email obscuring), so instead of trying to super-optimise a worker, it should be a worker API function, or an overall CloudFlare feature (maybe a PageRule)

Comment: Someone might make a CloudFlare App for this one day - https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/developer/docs/getting-started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to process with a TransformStream so that processing is async and doesn't require memory buffering (for scalability and to minimise GC) - there's only a 5ms CPU time budget.

**Overview**:

- To use for yourself, change the strings `forHeadStart`, `forHeadEnd`, and `forBodyEnd`.
- This deferredInjection approach is the recommended way that minimises CPU time for the worker. It's more efficient because it only needs to parse the very start of the HTML. The other approach requires parsing of the whole head section for headInjection, and if you use bodyInjection it practically needs to parse the whole html response.
- The deferredInjection approach works by injecting the content into the start of the head tag, then on the client-side at runtime your HTML content will be deployed to the desired places.
- You can inject directly if needed using `headInjection` and/or `bodyInjection`. Uncommenting related code, including code in `injectScripts`, and setting the strings for tagBytes that will be encoded.
- This solution will only parse HTML content types
- This solution works directly on bytes (not strings) for better efficiency. Searching for the bytes of the end-tag strings.
- You could potentially target more end-tags, but usually you don't need to target more than these two
- Processes data with streaming (the whole HTML string is not cached in memory). This lowers peak memory usage and speeds up time to first byte.
- Handles a rare edge case where the closing  tag is on a text read boundary. I believe a boundary might occur every ~1000 bytes (TCP packets 1000-1500 bytes each), and this can vary due to gzip compression.
- Keeps the injection parsing code separate for the code to simply forward the rest for clarity.
- You can disable the second body-tag injector by commenting it out if you don't need it - that will speed up processing.
- I have tested this exact code for myself and it works. There might be remaining bugs (depending on location of closing  tag, and depending if your server replies with partial html templates (body only)). I may have fixed one today 2019-06-28

**Code**

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.passThroughOnException();
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Fetch and log a request
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  const response = await fetch(request);

  var ctype = response.headers.get('content-type');
  if (ctype.startsWith('text/html') === false)
    return response; //Only parse html body

  let { readable, writable } = new TransformStream();
  let promise = injectScripts(response.body, writable);
  return new Response(readable, response);
}

let encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8');

let deferredInjection = function() {
    let forHeadStart = `<script>var test = 1; //Start of head section</script>`;
    let forHeadEnd = `<script>var test = 2; //End of head section</script>`;
    let forBodyEnd = `<script>var test = 3; //End of body section</script><button>click</button>`;

    let helper = `
    ${forHeadStart}
    <script>
        function appendHtmlTo(element, htmlContent) {
            var temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.innerHTML = htmlContent;
            while (temp.firstChild) {
                element.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
            };
        }

        let forHeadEnd = "${ btoa(forHeadEnd) }";
        let forBodyEnd = "${ btoa(forBodyEnd) }";

        if (forHeadEnd.length > 0) appendHtmlTo(document.head, atob(forHeadEnd)); 
    if (forBodyEnd.length > 0) window.onload = function() {
      appendHtmlTo(document.body, atob(forBodyEnd));
    };

    </script>
    `;
    return {
        forInjection: encoder.encode(helper),
        tagBytes: encoder.encode("<head>"),
        insertAfterTag: true
    };

}();

// let headInjection = {
    // forInjection: encoder.encode("<script>var test = 1;</script>"),
    // tagBytes: encoder.encode("</head>"), //case sensitive
    // insertAfterTag: false
// };
// let bodyInjection = {
    // forInjection: encoder.encode("<script>var test = 1;</script>"),
    // tagBytes: encoder.encode("</body>"), //case sensitive
    // insertAfterTag: false
// }

//console.log(bodyTagBytes);
encoder = null;

async function injectScripts(readable, writable) {
  let processingState = {
    readStream: readable,
    writeStream: writable,
    reader: readable.getReader(),
    writer: writable.getWriter(),
    leftOvers: null, //data left over after a closing tag is found
    inputDone: false,
    result: {charactersFound: 0, foundIndex: -1, afterHeadTag: -1} //Reused object for the duration of the request
  };


  await parseForInjection(processingState, deferredInjection);

  //await parseForInjection(processingState, headInjection);

  //await parseForInjection(processingState, bodyInjection);

  await forwardTheRest(processingState);      
}



///Return object will have foundIndex: -1, if there is no match, and no partial match at the end of the array
///If there is an exact match, return object will have charactersFound:(tagBytes.Length)
///If there is a partial match at the end of the array, return object charactersFound will be < (tagBytes.Length)
///The result object needs to be passed in to reduce Garbage Collection - we can reuse the object
function searchByteArrayChunkForClosingTag(chunk, tagBytes, result)
{   
  //console.log('search');
    let searchStart = 0;
  //console.log(tagBytes.length);
    //console.log(chunk.length);

    for (;;) {
        result.charactersFound = 0;
        result.foundIndex = -1;
        result.afterHeadTag = -1;
    //console.log(result);

        let sweepIndex = chunk.indexOf(tagBytes[0], searchStart);
        if (sweepIndex === -1)
            return; //Definitely not found

        result.foundIndex = sweepIndex;
        sweepIndex++;
        searchStart = sweepIndex; //where we start searching from next
        result.charactersFound++;   
        result.afterHeadTag = sweepIndex;

    //console.log(result);

        for (let i = 1; i < tagBytes.length; i++)
        {
            if (sweepIndex === chunk.length) return; //Partial match
            if (chunk[sweepIndex++] !== tagBytes[i]) { result.charactersFound = 0; result.afterHeadTag = -1; break; } //Failed to match (even partially to boundary)
            result.charactersFound++;
            result.afterHeadTag = sweepIndex; //Because we work around the actual found tag in case it's across a boundary
        }   

    if (result.charactersFound === tagBytes.length)
          return; //Found
    }

}

function continueSearchByteArrayChunkForClosingTag(chunk, tagBytes, lastSplitResult, result)
{
  //console.log('continue');
    //Finish the search (no need to check the last buffer at all)
    //console.log('finish the search');
    result.charactersFound = lastSplitResult.charactersFound; //We'll be building on the progress from the lastSplitResult
    result.foundIndex = (-1 * result.charactersFound); //This won't be used, but a negative value is indicative of chunk spanning
    let sweepIndex = 0;
    result.afterHeadTag = 0;
    for (let i = lastSplitResult.charactersFound; i < tagBytes.length; i++) //Zero-based
    {
        if (sweepIndex === chunk.length) return result; //So we support working on a chunk that's smaller than the tagBytes search size
        if (chunk[sweepIndex++] !== tagBytes[i]) { result.charactersFound = 0; result.afterHeadTag = -1; break; }
        result.charactersFound++;
        result.afterHeadTag = sweepIndex;
    }
}

function continueOrNewSearch(chunk, tagBytes, lastSplitResult, result)
{
  //console.log('continueOrNewSearch');
      if (lastSplitResult == null)
          searchByteArrayChunkForClosingTag(chunk, tagBytes, result);
      else
      {
          continueSearchByteArrayChunkForClosingTag(chunk, tagBytes, lastSplitResult, result);
        if (result.charactersFound === tagBytes.length)
            return result;
        else
            return searchByteArrayChunkForClosingTag(chunk, tagBytes, result); //Keep searching onward
      }
}

async function parseForInjection(processingState, injectionJob)
{
  if (processingState.inputDone) return; //Very edge case: Somehow </head> is never found?            
  if (!injectionJob) return;
  if (!injectionJob.tagBytes) return;
  if (!injectionJob.forInjection) return;

  let reader = processingState.reader;
  let writer = processingState.writer;
  let result = processingState.result;
  let tagBytes = injectionJob.tagBytes;
  //(reader, writer, tagBytes, forInjection)

  let lastSplitResult = null;
  let chunk = null;
  processingState.inputDone = false;
  for (;;) {
    if (processingState.leftOvers)
      {
      chunk = processingState.leftOvers;
      processingState.leftOvers = null;
      }
      else
      {
      let readerResult = await reader.read();
      chunk = readerResult.value;
      processingState.inputDone = readerResult.done;
      }

      if (processingState.inputDone) {
        if (lastSplitResult !== null) {
            //Very edge case: Somehow tagBytes is never found?            
            console.log('edge');
                  throw 'tag not found'; //Causing the system to fall back to the direct request
        }
        await writer.close();
        return true;
      }   
      //console.log(value.length);

        continueOrNewSearch(chunk, tagBytes, lastSplitResult, result)
      //console.log(result);

      if (result.charactersFound === tagBytes.length) //Complete match
      {
        //Inject
        //console.log('inject');
        if (result.foundIndex > 0)
        {
          let partValue = chunk.slice(0, result.foundIndex);
          //console.log(partValue);
          await writer.write(partValue);
        }
        console.log('injected');
        if (parseForInjection.insertAfterTag)
        {
            await writer.write(injectionJob.forInjection);
            await writer.write(injectionJob.tagBytes);
        }
        else
        {
            await writer.write(injectionJob.tagBytes);
            await writer.write(injectionJob.forInjection);
        }
        let remainder = chunk.slice(result.afterHeadTag, chunk.length - 1);
        processingState.leftOvers = remainder;
        lastSplitResult = null;
        return;
      }

      if (lastSplitResult !== null)
      {
        //console.log('no match over boundary');
        //The remainder wasn't found, so write the partial match from before (maybe `<` or `</`)
        let failedLastBit = injectionJob.tagBytes.slice(0, lastSplitResult.charactersFound);
        await writer.write(failedLastBit);
        lastSplitResult = null;
      }

      if (result.charactersFound === 0)
      {
        //console.log('not found')
        await writer.write(chunk);
        continue;
      }

      if (result.charactersFound < tagBytes.length)
      {
        //console.log('boundary: ' + result.charactersFound);
        lastSplitResult = result;
        let partValue = chunk.slice(0, result.foundIndex);
        //console.log(partValue);
        await writer.write(partValue);
        continue;
      }
  }
}

async function forwardTheRest(processingState)
{
  try
  {
  if (processingState.inputDone) return; //Very edge case: Somehow </head> is never found?            

  if (processingState.leftOvers)
  {
    chunk = processingState.leftOvers;
    await processingState.writer.write(chunk);
  }

  processingState.reader.releaseLock();
  processingState.writer.releaseLock();

  await processingState.readStream.pipeTo(processingState.writeStream);

  //Should there be an explicit close method called? I couldn't find one
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

---

**Further explanation of working directly with (utf-8) bytes:**

- Only working with byte values. This is possible at least by searching for the first distinctive utf-8 byte of a character (< 128 and > 192). But in this case, we're searching for `</head>` which is made up of lower-than-128 bytes, very easy to work with.
- Given the nature of searching for utf-8 (which is the trickiest), this should work with ['utf-8', 'utf8', 'iso-8859-1', 'us-ascii']. You will need to change the snippet encoder to match.
- This isn't thoroughly tested. The boundary case, didn't trigger for me.  Ideally, we would have a testing rig for the core functions
- thanks to Kenton Varda for challenging me
- Please let me know if there's a CloudFlare workers way to do pipeTo in the forwardTheRest function
- You might find `continueOrNewSearch` and the two sub-functions to be an interesting approach to finding multi-bytes across a chunk boundary. Up until the boundary we just count how many bytes are found. There's no need to keep those bytes (we know what they are). Then on the next chunk we continue where we left off. We always cut the array buffer around the header, and make sure we write the header bytes (using the tagBytes)

Comment: FWIW this will be much more efficient (less likely to hit the CPU time limit) if you can use `readableStream.pipeTo(writableStream)` instead of the loop in `forwardTheRest()`, but I suppose you will need somehow to ensure that you cleanly break between UTF-8 sequences so that you can drop the encoder/decoder.

Comment: @KentonVarda yes, true. It is technically feasible, but it would probably require a custom TextDecoder (with various ways to make that as efficient as the built-in one), that would be able to say whether it was still midway through a utf-8 character or not. Then the provision of one byte at a time to clear (and writing) then pipeTo after that. The missing piece is a TextDecoder with isChewingStill() :)

Comment: Or, instead of TextDecoding then looking for the end tag as text, it could look for the end tag using the byte values. This could be done in a way that also properly tracks utf-8 character boundaries, and also sheds unneeded data that isn't 6x bytes close to a chunk barrier when "</head>" is very likely to be on the chunk boundary.

Comment: It looks like you can look at the bytes to work out if it's the end of a character. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. The first value is either < 128 or > 192, for the other bytes the will never be < 128, nor > 192. (From what I gather) @KentonVarda

Comment: @KentonVarda see "More efficient forwardTheRest function:" that I added. I didn't test it, because I believe it will be better to go direct to a pure values approach. The match will certainly involve single-byte characters, this means the remainder of the values after the match is certainly already utf-8 aligned.

Comment: readableStream doesn't appear to have pipeTo as an available method

Comment: @KentonVarda I did it, see "Most efficient method overall:" section. It needs more testing and maturing, and if you can help with finding a `pipeTo` strategy for forwardTheRest, that would be great.

Comment: `pipeTo()` is a method on `ReadableStream`, not on `reader`. Remember that you got `reader` by calling `stream.getReader()`. You need to release the reader when you are done with it by calling `reader.releaseLock()`, then you can call `pipeTo()` on the original `ReadableStream` object. Similarly you will need to release the `Writer` and then use the `WritableStream` object as the parameter to `pipeTo()`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/pipeTo

Comment: Thanks @KentonVarda done. For injecting into the body, I think it will be better to insert a script only just after the `<head>` tag. The script that's inserted will run and in turn append the content to the end of the body. This way we're only scanning to readch <head>, but then the rest of the content is piped through.

Comment: deferred-injection is now available in my answer as the default approach