# What is the explicit and direct code for facebook pixel

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-pixel

(I'm still improving this question, feel free to articulate my question better for me. I have completed my own answer and that should help frame this question better)

Explicit - means "direct" in this situation. The one provided by Facebook is minified and includes a deferred script tag injector.

How does this break down into logical parts that could be more explicitly coded without minification and without the deferred script load? How could I directly include the script tag for https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js?

Current prescribed block:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'your-pixel-id-goes-here');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" 
       src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=your-pixel-id-goes-here&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Why an `explicit` version might be desirable:

- Efficiency - which can mean a lot of things
- Verbosity and clarity
- Education - to learn how these kinds of scripts work and how you might do your own
- Integration - you might have something like SquareSpace where you accept a pixel-id as a parameter for your "Facebook" integration

I plan to use a working answer along with [How to inject javascript in existing HTML response with node.js and cloudflare workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660355/how-to-inject-javascript-in-existing-html-response-with-node-js-and-cloudflare-w) for myself. So please don't reply with "You don't want this because I don't want this" kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2019-06-24 and given the current prescribed block:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'your-pixel-id-goes-here');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" 
       src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=your-pixel-id-goes-here&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

There are 4 distinct parts:

1. Window variables and double-installation collision. The default code seems to load the script asyncronously, and sets up the fbq function to queue up commands until the script is loaded.
2. Inclusion of the dependent script tag
3. Using the fbq commands to init and track the page view
4. Loading an image if there is no javascript support

Assuming you have full control over the content of the web page, and you know there won't be duplicate attempts to load the facebook pixel - this can be deployed more explicitly with:

1) Put this script load before the following in the head section

```
<script async src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"></script>
```

2) Put this variable block of script code in the header after [1]

```
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];}(window, document,'script'); //Same as usual but with the script injection part removed.

  fbq('init', 'your-pixel-id-goes-here');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
```

3) Put this noscript section at the end of the body

```
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" 
       src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=your-pixel-id-goes-here&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
```

(Successfully tested)